# SvelteKit page data doesn't always update when opening new page in the same dynamic route

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a route structure `/items/[category]`. When the user is browsing `/items/category1` and then tries to go to a another page in the same route (eg. `/items/category2`) the page data usually updates to show category2 items, but not always. Sometimes the URL updates in the browser but the page data still shows items from the previous URL.

My `+page.server.js` for `/items/[category]` looks like:

```js
import { getItems } from '$lib/services/ItemService';
export const csr = false;
export const load = ({ locals, params }) => {
    return {
        items: getItems(locals, `category = "${params.itemCategory}"`)
    };
};
```

And my `+page.svelte` is:

```html
<script>
   import { ItemCard } from '$lib/components';
   export let data
   let items = data.items
</script>
...
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 px-4 gap-6">   
   {#each items as item}
      <ItemCard {item}/>
   {/each}
</div>
```

The `getItems()` function retrieves JSON data from pocketbase and is working correctly.

I read that adding the `export const csr = false;` to the `+page.server.js` should solve the problem, but it appears that the page still isn't always re-loading data from the server when swapping between routes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You change local state non-reactively:

```js
let items = data.items
```

If `data` is updated by the router, `items` will not.

Making it reactive might fix the issue:

```js
$: items = data.items
```

You can also destructure props reactively, which requires additional parentheses:

```js
$: ({ items } = data)
```

[SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/state-management#component-and-page-state-is-preserved) on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```js
let categoryUrl = $page.params.category;
```

to

```js
$: categoryUrl = $page.params.category;
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'params' attribute is not reactive if you navigate from a similar route (e.g. /items/category2 -> /items/category3).
What worked for me for a similar issue was:

```
import { navigating } from '$app/stores';
let categoryUrl = $page.params.category;
$: {
    categoryUrl = typeof window !== 'undefined' ?  window.location.href.split('/').pop() : $page.params.category;
}
$: if($navigating) {
    let newUrl = typeof window !== 'undefined' ?  window.location.href.split('/').pop() : $page.params.category;
    if(categoryUrl !== newUrl) { 
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: `params` is reactive, or rather, the store that it is in is. If you just write `{$page.params.category}` somewhere in the template, it should update just fine. Maybe you navigated without using `goto` or had some intermediary variable that was not declared reactively.

Answer (score -1):

This problem has been bugging me for days, and I finally found that the easiest solution is to use `window.location.href`.

Write your code like this:

```html
<button on:click={() => {
        window.location.href = `/path/${id}`;
      }}>
Go
</button>
```

Comment: This will cause a page reload, which is wasteful. SvelteKit has a client-side router that only loads data that is not already loaded. Your page is probably mutating state non-reactively.