# Sveltekit returns the right page only when in a new Tab

Tags: hyperlink, rendering, sveltekit

I have written a books page in sveltekit, on a book detail page at the bottom i render similar books, the thumbnails are fine and also the href link. However when i click on one of the similar books, the same book is loaded, which is wrong, but when i open in a new tab, then the similar book is loaded.
i can't understand why this behaviour, anybody an idea?
I already deployed it, and you can see it on this page: https://cdl-protokolle.com/buecher

Click on one of the books, and try to click on the similar books.

This is the Book Component which is rendering the thumbnails:

```
<script>
    import { getImg } from "$lib/functions/getImg";
    export let book = {id:0,img:"",title:""};
    // console.log('Book Komponenten Ausgabe ******************  book id ist ', book.id);
    // console.log(typeof(book.id));
</script>

<div class="bg-gray-200 w-full h-[300px] ">

    <div  class=" pt-2 overflow-auto">
            <a href={`/buecher/${book.id}`}>
                <img class="mx-auto" width="150" src="{getImg(book.img, book.id)}" alt="{book.title}" />
            </a>
            <div class="p-3">
                <a href={`/buecher/${book.id}`}>
                
                    {book.title}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

https://cdl-protokolle.com/buecher

btw. this page is using the same book component, and the links are all fine and behave just as expected, only under a book detail page it does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SvelteKit page data doesn't always update when opening new page in the same dynamic route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74549820/sveltekit-page-data-doesnt-always-update-when-opening-new-page-in-the-same-dyna)